# How do I change a bootstrap class' sass property in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

to clarify I'm using react-bootstrap and trying to use bootstrap. I have the following:

```
import React from 'react'

// bootstrap
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MainDisplay = () => {
  return (
    <div className='MainDisplayContainer'>

        <div className='Header'>
            <button>Header</button>
        </div>

        <div className='Body'>
            body
        </div>

        <div className='Footer'>
            footer
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default MainDisplay
```

and this is the sass:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.Header{
    button{
        @extend .btn;
    }
}

.Body{

}

.Footer{

}
```

Essentially if I were to do this inline it would simply be:

```
<button className='btn btn-info'>Header</button>
```

but how would I do this in the sass file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really understanding what you're needing to change in the SASS file but per your `button` example in React Bootstrap per the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/) if you want:

```
<button className='btn btn-info'>Header</button>
```

you would use the variant info:

```
<Button variant="info">Header</Button>
```